# Unity 2D Implementation of buildings in TileMap

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've developed 2d rpg top down game and I faced with next problem:
What's the best way to place building (houses, blocks of flats, etc) on tile map?

Currently I found only two ways:
1. Use plenty of scenes or master scene for buildings (and configure switch bettween levels
2. Create places outside the camera and teleport players there.

I wouldn't like to use this methods. I'd like to place objects on the tile map and have got the opportinity enter there without swich scene or teleportation.

Could you give me any ideas?

Comment: Why not add a 2d image sprite?

Comment: Have you considered working with layers? like photoshop, paint.net and more has implemented. I have made a tool as such, but the layers are working as tile map each. and then aswell i have something called overlays, which can be applied ontop of each tile.